# Optimise to find objects with the highest field value in array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I made a function that returns an array list with the people having the highest `number` field. But I'm pretty sure that this can be optimized

```java
public  ArrayList<Membre> findOlder(){
    ArrayList<Membre>olderPersonnes = new ArrayList<Membre>();
    int higher = 0;
    for (Membre membre : membresDeLaFamille) {
        if (membre.getNumber() > higher) {
            higher = membre.getNumber();
        }
    }
    for (Membre membre: membresDeLaFamille) {
        if (membre.getNumber() == higher) {
            olderPersonnes.add(membre);
        }
    }
    return olderPersonnes;
}
```

Comment: Asking for optimization for working code is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: [`Stream.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) maybe.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp while Streams have built-in functions for "max" or "filter", they incur a performance penalty and should be avoided for simple cases where performance is an issue.

Comment: @TomElias This hardly depends on the use case and only the author can give us details about the size of the **membresDeLaFamille** collection.  
For better readability and maintainability i aggree with Johnny Mopp.  
You can exit the method immediately, if membresDeLaFamille is empty. Max might not be the correct streaming operation depending on the fact if multiple persons can have the same number assigned.

Comment: In terms of readability it's not great, but in terms of runtime complexity you can't have better.

Comment: in principal, i'm against using Streams in functions where the input parameter isn't already a Stream just to "look cool with lambdas". getting a Stream out of a Collection is a costly operation.

Comment: Keeping the list sorted would reduce the complexity of this operation. You can change to a binary search and get ~log N.

Answer (score 1):

optimize? depends on what you're optimizing for.

complexity - this is an O(n) loop, it is already the least "complex" it can be. (findmax in an unsorted array of size n -> O(n))

running time - can be improved if instead of the second loop you just keep a reference to the "membre" that you find inside the first loop, and return that.

Comment: "instead of the second loop you just keep a reference to the "membre" that you find inside the first loop" -> What if there's more than one?

Comment: add them to a collection like he does in the second loop. use >= instead of >

Comment: Gonna waste more time newing up and destroying collections than looping once again IMO. Perhaps with a linked list, but...

Comment: IIRC, for(each) loop uses Iterator behind the scenes, that's also a waste if we're nitpicking ;)

Comment: Just saying that I dont think you can necessarily claim that running time will be improved with the suggestion you made :P Still +1 because I think you can't reasonably optimize further.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do better than O(1) runtime complexity (unless the list is sorted already), so this is already optimized.

In terms of readability you could do better (arguably) using declarative (and functional concepts) vs imperative programming, but it certainly wouldn't be faster.

e.g.

```java
public static List<Member> findOlder() {
    return membresDeLaFamille.stream()
        .map(Member::getNumber)
        .max(Integer::compare)
        .map(maxAge -> membresDeLaFamille.stream().filter(m -> maxAge.equals(m.getNumber())))
        .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the list of *multiple* family members with the maximum number may be retrieved in the one pass if the input list `membresDeLaFamille` is unsorted, and as soon as the new "max" is found, current list should be cleared:

```java
public List<Membre> findOlder() {
    List<Membre> olderPersonnes = new ArrayList<>();
    int higher = 0;
    for (Membre membre : membresDeLaFamille) {
        if (membre.getNumber() >= higher) {
            if (membre.getNumber() > higher) {
                higher = membre.getNumber();
                olderPersonnes.clear();
            }
            olderPersonnes.add(membre);
        }
    }
    return olderPersonnes;
}
```

---

If the input list happens to be already sorted by the values returned by `Membre::getNumber`, then the max value(s) is/are surely placed at some end of the input list (depending on the ascending or descending order of sorting).